# Bash Code Injection Vulnerability On Linux

Tags: bash, security, upgrade, vulnerability

Found a bug in Linux, a bash code injection vulnerability.

The solution to this is the update the `bash` package.

```
yum update bash
```

My Question is "do I need to reboot the system"? We have 4000 servers in our environment, it will be hard to do reboot on all the systems.

Comment: It depends on the vulnerability. In general, you wouldn't need to reboot, but you might need to restart some services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply read documentation on this vulnerability and update instructions. E.g. redhat provides extremely detailed [information](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1200223):

> Do I need to reboot or restart services after installing the update
>   for CVE-2014-6271 and CVE-2014-7169?
>
> If your system uses exported Bash functions, restarting affected
>   services is recommended. Affected interactive users may have to
>   re-login, and screen or tmux sessions may need to be restarted.
>
> The Bash update provided to fix these issues changes the names of
>   exported functions in the environment. If a function is exported by
>   the old version of Bash, it is not recognized by newly started Bash
>   processes after the update, and essentially becomes undefined.
>   Restarting the services ensures that the new version of Bash exports
>   functions under the expected name, making it visible again.
>
> To find out which services need to be restarted (or which users have
>   to re-login), execute the following command after updating:
>
> $ grep -l -z '[^)]=() {' /proc/[1-9]*/environ | cut -d/ -f3
>
> The returned PIDs belong to processes which are using the old exported
>   function definitions in their environment. These processes must be
>   restarted. To discover which service started a certain PID and needs
>   restarting, on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, use the following command:
>
> $ systemctl status
>
> On Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 and earlier, use the pstree -p or ps
>   -axuf command and look for a particular PID.

PS. If you have 4000 servers, you definitely should hire someone who can perform all the maintenance stuff. At least with such basic questions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have someone for this activity, but just wanted double check with some of the IT Geeks.